# How many pending transactions can I create with the same nonce?

Tags: mining, nonce, txpool

Recently I cancelled a pending transaction by resending an other transaction with the same nounce and a higher gas price in order to have the new transaction mined faster. This was useful in my case.

However is it not possible to spam the network by doing this ? What happens if I send thousands of transactions with the same nounce at the same time ? Will they stay in the queue until at least one is being mined ?

Comment: Presumably (not on a full computer to look at source code) the mining node software will process transactions in descending order (roughly) of gas price. Thus, you might be able to spam a less-intelligent node and eat up its RAM. A smarter node probably prunes the duplicate with lower gas price. You can always spam the network with garbage transactions that consume CPU cycles and bandwidth and don't cost any ether.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the node you are connecting to but most of them replace the transaction that has the same nonce and address

In parity, for example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/c49beccadcd3c60c9fd90d1393921b91598c8eb0/ethcore/src/miner/transaction_queue.rs#L389)
In mantis, [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/mantis/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/iohk/ethereum/transactions/PendingTransactionsManager.scala#L71)